# What is the meaning of "new {}" in Scala?

Tags: scala, anonymous-types

I am studying about `.sbt` extension file reference docs. What codes I am confused is:

```
lazy val version = new {
    val finatra = "2.1.2"
}
```

I know val `finatra` can be accessed by `version.finatra`, but it seems like "object singleton." Such like this:

```
object version {
    val finatra = "2.1.2"
}
```

In this case, I can also access val `finatra` by `version.finatra`.
I know the later one is the way to create "object singleton".
How about the former one? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, it is creating new instance of [Anonymous Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_type)

According to the [Scala Language Spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions):

---

Consider the following structural instance creation expression:

```
new { def getName() = "aaron" }
```

This is a shorthand for the general instance creation expression

```
new AnyRef{ def getName() = "aaron" }
```

The latter is in turn a shorthand for the block

```
{ class anon$X extends AnyRef{ def getName() = "aaron" }; new anon$X }
```

---