# Can not instantiate trait with no methods without empty code block

Tags: scala, traits, anonymous-class

I found an interesting condition with traits:

```
scala> trait Thing[A]
defined trait Thing

scala> val myThing: Thing[Int] = new Thing[Int]
       error: trait Thing is abstract; cannot be instantiated

scala> val myThing: Thing[Int] = new Thing[Int] { }
myThing: Thing[Int] = $anon$1@135f160e
```

Why does having the code block allow me to create an instance of the Thing trait?

Answer (score 6):

It's a feature of the language called an *anonymous class*. When you write `new Thing[Int] { }`, the compiler creates a new class with the name `$anon$1` (or something similar) that extends `Thing[Int]`, and then creates a new instance of `$anon$1`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot instantiate the trait directly. When adding the `{}`, you're creating an anonymous class which can be instantiated.

Similar question posted elsewhere:

- https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9297
- https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/9t1b9u/instantiation_of_traits/

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at it is the keyword `new` invokes a **constructor**, however trait does not have a constructor, so

```
new Thing[Int]
```

cannot be instantiated. But where is the constructor in

```
new Thing[Int] { }
```

you might ask? Well, the "empty code block" actually defines the constructor. This constructor indeed has no statements in it (besides invoking the super constructor), however now `new` at least has something to invoke. Similarly,

```
class Bar
trait Qux

new Bar // ok because class has a constructor (by default)
new Qux // error because trait has no constructor
```

The precise term to search for in SLS is [general instance creation expression](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#instance-creation-expressions) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826127/5205022).

Comment: I don't think it's a _useful_ way of looking in this particular situation; 1. it doesn't explain how/why `new Bar {}` works; 2. The "block" can contain declarations, not just statements. Adding a link to SLS _is_ useful, though.